# In OPENSSL , After SSL_Connect() i am getting SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, secure-gateway

I am using `SSL_Connect()` and return code is "-1" , with `SSL_get_error()` i can see that error is `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ`.

As per suggestion on one forum, where it suggested to keep calling `SSL_connect()` until this error goes. With this modification for first call i am getting error WANT_READ and for second call i am getting `SSL_ERROR_SSL`. After that for all subsequent calls it is `SSL_ERROR_SSL` only and as per description of this error it looks something went wrong in `SSL library`.

Can some one who resolved `SSL_connect` successfully provide some help.

My code is a plain sequence of calling :
 1. SSL_library_init()
 2. Creating methods(v23) and context using this meth
 3. context has not been modified and it plain as created.
 4. SSL object is created using this plain ctx and ssl_connect is called on this ssl after calling SSL_set_fd()

Please let me know if i am doing some thing wrong in this sequence or if i am missing something ?

Is it required to load various things to `ctx` like certificates and verify locations before using it , if yes what are the bare minimum things required.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

If it wants a read you have to do a read, or block in select() until OP_READ fires if non-blocking, and then call SSL_Connect() again.
If it wants a write you have to do a write, or block in select() until OP_WRITE fires if non-blocking, and then call SSL_Connect() again.

See [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_connect.html).

Comment: and you have to do again the call with very same arguments ( ie same buffers ) not a copy of them. In case of SSL_Connect it is SSL *ssl that should be the same. My remark is less in SSL_Connect() relevant than in SSL_read() of course.